memoir: is there a way to preserve parenthesis at subcaption numbering and remove them at refencing them?
How to preserve parenthesis at subcaption numbering using \subbottom of memoir command and remove them at refencing them?
Please see the following MWE:
\documentclass{memoir}
    \captiondelim{\null\newline}
    \captionnamefont{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
    \captiontitlefont{\small\sffamily\linespread{.84}\selectfont}
\newsubfloat{figure}
\shortsubcaption
    \subcaptionlabelfont{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
    \subcaptionfont{\small\sffamily}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \setkeys{Gin}{height=33mm, width=\linewidth}
    
\subbottom[standard memoir subcaption \dots   \label{fig:subfig5a}]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}

\medskip  
\subbottom[standard memoir subcaption \dots  \label{fig:subfig5b}]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}

\caption{\lipsum[66]}
\label{fig:5}
    \end{figure}

In figure \ref{fig:5} are subfigures \ref{fig:subfig5a} and \ref{fig:subfig5b} \dots

\noindent%
However, I like that referencing would be like this:

In figure \ref{fig:5} are subfigures 1.1a and 1.1b \dots
\end{document}

Hot manage that referencing those subfigures has style as shown in the last text line in image?
